# Sound is coming out of speakers, audio isn't accessible in applications?

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, alsa, manjaro

My audio sounds perfectly fine coming out of my speakers, but I noticed when I check my audio levels in Pavucontrol or OBS, the audio bars are showing zero output.

[image]

However, when I send the playback to HDMI in Pavucontrol, both OBS and Pavucontrol pick up the audio perfectly fine!

[image]

Any clue where I messed up in my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming/deleting my `.config/pulse/` folder and restarting PulseAudio fixed it for me!

I remembered that I messed around with combined audio input and output sinks a while back, apparently the commands I ran changed some of the configuration settings permanently. Clearing the configuration solved everything luckily.